# TypeError: Method Uint8Array.length called on incompatible receiver nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node.js and fs.writeFile() to write JSON to a file, approximately 1-2.5MB of data, though, at times it gives me this error;

```
TypeError: Method Uint8Array.length called on incompatible receiver [object Object]
    at Buffer.get length (native)
    at writeFd (fs.js:1207:45)
    at fs.js:1198:7
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

I don't know why or how, nor how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a script that ran for about two weeks, writing data into around 3.5 thousand files on random intervals on an AWS instance. Each of the files was maximum 2 MB.

What happened there was that there were likely too many file pointers open at the time, plus that some memory resources could not be freed because I found a `swapfile` file in the root folder of my instance that was exactly 4.0 GB, which was the actual memory limit. So it seems the os ran out of resources because of this heavy lifting.

Proper resource management might be the solution to your issue!